# Creating and hosting our own private android store

Tags: android

currently we have a few apps we've developed for our own organization's needs in house. Of course like everyone else we occasinally do updates for those apps. Usually this involves everyone downloading .apk files and updating with the new app.

Since these apps are relatively secure and could cause legal issues if released into the wild, management is somewhat loathe to put these apps on the Google Cloud in any form (even a private store).

Ergo I'm trying to research the idea of creating a private store containing apps that we host on a server in house, where people would connect and download apps.

Does any such store app/framework exist for this?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow".

Comment: Fair enough sent in a vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer, look for F-Droid out there.  Pretty simple really.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually recommend using a Google Play Private Channel here. See the details here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2623322?hl=en

This'll do exactly what you need - allow you to restrict the distribution of files to some kind of organization.

Comment: Not gonna happen, these apps have legal issues going external in any fashion.

Comment: I'm not convinced that hosting the server in-house intrinsically makes it more secure - lots of companies who were doing their own hosting have been hacked (Target *et. al*, more recently the Democratic National Convention - not sure offhand who was doing their hosting for them though). Heck, even the NSA might have been hacked recently: http://www.nytimes.com/2016/08/17/us/shadow-brokers-leak-raises-alarming-question-was-the-nsa-hacked.html - plus, the simple fact that people have it on their phones makes it vulnerable to release - 2.1 million people had their phones stolen last year.

Comment: Repeat previous point, not security, legal issues some of it concerning security, but its a battle I can't fight right now

Comment: Fair enough, both legitimate reasons to host in-house. Obviously it can't be *completely* separated from the security issue though (I assume if someone hacked the server or stole a phone with the code on it that would be legally bad too; I'm assuming the goal here is to avoid it getting out of the organization by *any* means). That being said, I assume you've taken security precautions like making sure that phones that it's installed on are password-protected and things like that?

Comment: yeah phones in question are about as locked down as they can get, the reality is some of the apps to be in this store are in the "We  wouldn't care if it were shared" level of security, but some of the apps concern my organization's law enforcement unit, and there is all sorts of legal framework when dealing with law enforcement security, privacy and accountability/auditing where I'm at.